# Clone one branch onto another

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

So, I'm developing something and have a development branch. This was actually supposed to be called develop. I'm pretty far into this project already. I created a develop branch. How would I clone this branch just as it is into my develop branch?

Comment: What the relationship between `development` and `develop`? Do they share any commits?

Comment: er, `git branch new old` will give you a new branch pointing to the same commit as the old branch, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a new branch based on the development branch?
I generally use the app GitExtensions and it has a simple way to just say create new branch from the current branch.

Comment: I tried merging the development branch onto the develop branch but that didn't work. Is there a way to delete the develop branch, and then create a new develop branch off of the development branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to replace the development branch with the branch you're doing the development on (let's call it `x`) you can just delete the `develop` and re-branch `x` with that name:

```
git branch -D develop
git checkout -b develop x
```

If develop was already upstream, you'd have to force push it.

```
git push -f origin develop
```

Of course you'd lose anything that is on the current `develop` that wasn't on `master`, but from your description it wasn't clear if `develop` was purely a named off-shoot that work had not actually begun on.